# How to fix video title in lock screen of iPhone and iPad

Tags: kaltura

When I watch a video and then I lock the screen the lock screen will be view the name of the video.

This behavior is not right for my application because I have random names in kaltura and would like to override the name by my CMS.

On android environments the page title is shown but on ios devices the cryptic kaltura title.

How can I override the title on iPhone and iPad devices.

I have following config.

```
    kWidget.embed({
        'targetId': targetId,
        'wid': '_' + kalturaPlayer.partnerId,
        'uiconf_id': kalturaPlayer.uiConfId,
        'entry_id': this.entryId,
        'flashvars': {
            'autoPlay': this.autoPlay,
            'autoMute': this.autoMute
            , "IframeCustomPluginCss1": kalturaPlayer.customCss
            , "mediaProxy": {
                "entry": {
                    "name": this.title
                }
            }
            , "topBarContainer": {
                "plugin": this.includeTopBar
            },
            "controlBarContainer": {
                "hover": true
            }
        },
        'params': {
            'wmode': 'transparent'
        }
    });
```